# One instance variable for multiple values

Tags: java

I'm a Java beginner so bear with me

The requirements are only one instance variable, one constructor, and one method is allowed. Is it possible to make description(instance variable, not the constructor) store multiple values for a date(such as year, month and day)? Something like the code below. I can print it fine if there are multiple instance variables but not with one.

```
import java.util.Date;

public class MyDate {

    public Date description; //type might be wrong

    public MyDate(int year, int month, int day, String description) {
        //not sure what to put
    }

    public String toString() {
        //return d + "/" + m + "/" + y + " " + description;
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends...you could create a second class which maintained the details (year, month, day, description) in it's own instance fields, otherwise, you will need to maintain them within a `String` value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different way to store your value into one variable.

> 1. Store your values in key-value pair using [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).
> 2. Store values in simple [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) or [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) and retrieve using index.
> 3. Make one class include all your required attribute as instant member for that class. Create object of that class set value to
>      instant variable.

May one this way will help to solved your problem.

Sample Example :
1. Using `Map<String,Object>` :

```
public Map<String,Object> description; //type might be wrong

public MyDate(int year, int month, int day, String descriptionTxt) {
     description = new HashMap<String, Object>();
     description.put("year", year);
     description.put("month", month);
     description.put("day", day);
     description.put("desc", descriptionTxt);
}
```

2.Using `List<Object>` :

```
public List<Object> description; //type might be wrong

public MyDate(int year, int month, int day, String descriptionTxt) {
     description = new ArrayList<Object>();
     description.add(year);
     description.add( month);
     description.add(day);
     description.add(descriptionTxt);
}
```

3.Using Class  :

```
class MyClass
{
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;
    private String desc;

    //Getter and Setter Method
}  

 //MyDate class

 public MyClass description; //type might be wrong

 public void MyDate(int year, int month, int day, String descriptionTxt) {
     description = new MyClass();
     description.setYear(year);
     description.setMonth(month);
     description.setDay(day);
     description.setDesc(descriptionTxt);
 }
```